# Powershell: How to compare a byte string with a binary registry value

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a binary registry value that I'd like to check for consistency in a Powershell script.  I'm retrieving the value by:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\ORL\WinVNC3 -Name ACL).ACL
```

This returns a byte string as a result.

I then create a byte string variable that matches what I should expect then querying this value by exporting out the registry key through regedit.exe.  I then create a byte string from that text by prepending "0x" in front of each byte separated by a comma and typing is a [byte].  When I just eyeball both strings they are exactly the same.  However, when I:

```
$RegistryValue -eq $CreatedValue
```

they don't return True.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the types of your variables? The [comparison operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759(v=wps.620).aspx) work differently depending on type. Arrays and collections don't evaluate equality.

Comment: Both variables I was able to come up with were byte types.

Comment: What does `$RegistryValue.GetType().Fullname` return? There shouldn't be any "0x" in a variable of type [Byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Byte(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: $RegistryValue returns System.Byte[] for the type

Comment: What about `$CreatedValue.GetType().FullName`? The problem is that the -eq operator only works on scalar values if you want a boolean test. It behaviors differently for arrays and collections, which is what $RegistryValue is, an array of System.Byte[]. See the link above for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out by a combination of some different methods on my part and the Compare-Object cmdlet.  Thanks, Dallas.

1. Set the appropriate binary value in the registry.
2. Retrieve the value via:

$ValueItsSupposedToBe = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\ORL\WinVNC3 -Name ACL).ACL

1. Create a comma,separated string of the values and insert this string into the compare script.
2. In the compare script, split the string and convert it into a byte array.

[byte[]]$ValueItsSupposedToBe = $ValueItsSupposedToBe.Split(',')

1. Read the value currently set on another machine.

$CompareValue = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\ORL\WinVNC3 -Name ACL).ACL

1. If Compare-Object comes back as null, then they're equal.

Compare-Object $CompareValue $ValueItsSupposedTobe

Answer (score 5):

Try using the compare-object cmdlet.

```
Compare-Object $RegistryValue $CreatedValue
```

If they're equal, you should see the `==` operator in the results table.