# How to compare an item property to a string value

Tags: powershell

I am relatively new to PowerShell and cannot understand why my original attempts failed. I am attempting to validate the bit version of MS Office and perform actions off that. For whatever reason the strings were not comparing properly until I found a solution in the actual question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788086/powershell-how-to-compare-a-byte-string-with-a-binary-registry-value). Help understanding the difference between the two examples below would be much appreciated.

First attempt:

```
$getMSBitVersion= Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" | Select-Object -Property Platform

if( $getMSBitVersion -eq "x64" ){
    Write-Host "true"
} else {
    Write-Host "false"
}
```

Working solution:

```
$getMSBitVersion= (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" -Name Platform).Platform

if( $getMSBitVersion -eq "x64" ){
    Write-Host "true"
} else {
    Write-Host "false"
}
```

My assumption is the first is outputting an object instead of string and thus the comparison cannot be done. If this is the case, is the working solution the only way/best way to do this?

Comment: `Select -Property Platform` creates a new object with a single property named `Platform` - the second expression just gives you the raw value of the registry entry. It's like the difference between `@{ Platform = 'x64' }` vs just `'x64'`

Comment: Following up on Mathias comment, you have to expand the property `-ExpandProperty`. `(...)` allows you to let output from a command participate in an expression; it basically enumerates the properties for that return and using *Dot Notation* you referenced property getting just the value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mathias and Abraham.

From what I gather, the following are confirmed methods on how to make the desired comparison.

1: This will scope into the object property of "Platform" by using dot notation and return the string value instead of the whole object.

```
$getMSBitVersion= (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" -Name Platform).Platform

if( $getMSBitVersion -eq "x64" ){
    Write-Host "true"
} else {
    Write-Host "false"
}
```

2: This will take all the properties of the Path and pass through to Select-Object. Select-Object will take and expand the "Property" object and return it as a string.

```
$getMSBitVersion= Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Platform

if( $getMSBitVersion -eq "x64" ){
    Write-Host "true"
} else {
    Write-Host "false"
}
```

**I was unable to get this solution to function correctly, but should, in theory, work.**

3: This, in theory, should work, but the two objects are recognized differently and do not compare as intended.

```
$getMSBitVersion= Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" | Select-Object -Property Platform
$test= @{Platform="x64"}

if( Compare-Object $getMSBitVersion $test ){
    Write-Host "true"
} else {
    Write-Host "false"
}
```